# Conservative energy of the wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

If we take account of air resistance in the wave equation, we have an extra term proportional to speed,
$ρu_{tt} − Tu_{xx} + ru_t = 0$ , Where $r > 0 $
Show that the energy of this system,
$$
E = 1/2\int_{-∞}^\infty (ρu_t^{2}+Tu_x^{2})dx
$$
is decreasing in time.

Here's what I did,
$E = KE + PE$
$KE = ρ/2\int u_t^2dx$
$\frac{dKE}{dt}=ρ\int u_tu_{tt}dx$
By substituting $ρu_{tt} = Tu_{xx} - ru_t$ in the PDE we get,
$\frac{dKE}{dt}=T\int u_tu_{xx}dx-r\int u_t^2dx$
Apply integration by parts on first term,
$\frac{dKE}{dt}=Tu_tu_{x}-T\int u_{tx}u_{x}dx-r\int u_t^2dx$
The term $Tu_tu_{x}$ vanishes as x goes to $\infty$ and $-\infty$ So we are left with 
$\frac{dKE}{dt}=-T\int u_{tx}u_{x}dx-r\int u_t^2dx$

Alright now I don't seem to know what to do next, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It may be useful to first prove that, if the dissipative $r u_t$ term is missing, then the energy is conserved. From there it should be evident how the dissipative term spoils this.

Comment: so you're saying since $r\int u_t^2dx$ is negative, then the energy is negative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

\begin{align}\dot{E} &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty (\rho u_t u_{tt} + Tu_x u_{xt})\, dx\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty (u_t(Tu_{xx} - ru_t) + Tu_xu_{xt})\, dx\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty [T(u_tu_{xx} + u_xu_{xt}) - ru_t^2] dx\\
&= T\int_{-\infty}^\infty (u_tu_x)_x dx - r\int_{-\infty}^\infty u_t^2\, dx\\
&= T(0) - \int_{-\infty}^\infty u_t^2\, dx\\
&= -r\int_{-\infty}^\infty u_t^2\\
&\le 0.
\end{align}

Therefore, $E$ is decreasing in time.

Comment: Oh alright,so i was close. Thank you!

Comment: Question, how did you get your Energy from $E = 1/2\int_{-∞}^\infty (ρu_t^{2}+Tu_x^{2})dx$

Comment: I differentiated the energy.

Comment: so since the derivative of the energy is negative, it means that the energy is decreasing. Does it also mean that the energy is decreasing at a constant rate?

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be that $dE/dt$ is a constant.